# How to write an academic paper?

Tags: resources, research

I'm looking for resources on how to write an academic paper. The Web really lacks of those.

**Edit**: Standback's and A. Martin's answers perfectly illustrates what I expect.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with resources like [this guide](http://www.experiment-resources.com/write-a-research-paper.html), [this PDF essay](http://www.ambriana.com/C298_website/How_to_write_a_paper.pdf), or [this resource list](http://www-e.uni-magdeburg.de/hkersten/WritingPapers/Writlink.htm)? If these don't answer your questions, then by all means ask - but being more specific on what exactly you're missing would make for a much better question.

Comment: This question would be a good subject for an academic paper.

Comment: You should be more specific in order to get an answer...

Comment: What kind of an academic paper? Sciences or humanities? What are you writing about (hopefully you know)? Depending on the answers to these questions, you might be writing an essay, analysis, critique, review, thesis, or report, using APA, Chicago, MLA, CSE, ASA,or AAA format - all of which will change the answer to the question of how you go about writing your paper.

Comment: In response to your edit: the links I gave you were among the top five Google results for "how write academic paper". This is a "please Google this for me" question, and as such, kind of annoying. Especially with the rider about "the web really lack of those" - or do you think the web really lacks of search engines as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent paper about what NOT to do when writing a scientific paper. Do read it.

- [How to write consistently boring scientific literature](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0030-1299.2007.15674.x/full)